# .gitignore **/* but not <something>/*

Tags: git, wildcard, gitignore

I have a `.gitignore` (specifically in the webapp folder of a partially generated spring application) that contains:

```
**/*
!.gitignore
!META-INF/*
!WEB-INF/*
!index.jsp
```

I want to be ignoring all files except those with the negate lines, but the `!<some folder>/*` lines don't work and all files in those folders are ignored.

I tried replacing the `**/*` entry with: `*`, `/*`, `/**/*`, none of which solve the issue.

I would prefer not to explicitly list what not to ignore and not to explicitly add items, though I am currently doing so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: ignore files in the current directory exclusively, and don't ignore the folders whose contents I wish to track at all, rather than not ignoring the contents of those folders.

The resulting .gitignore file is:

```
/*
!.gitignore
!META-INF
!WEB-INF
```